# Python - Input from user is not recognized as "Y" or "N"

Tags: python, raw-input

I'm trying to write a simple program to get myself back into python after a long break caused by my personal life. The purpose of the program is to do as follows:

- Ask the user to enter a number equal to 5 (very simple, I know)
- Check if what the user inputs is valid
- Check if the user's input is equal to 5
- Ask the user if they would like to run the program again
- Run the program if the user inputs `y` or `Y`, and exit the program if the input is `n` or `N`

import os

```
askme = raw_input("Enter a number that is equal to 5: ")

def check_att(attrib):
    if int(attrib) == 5:
        os.system("cls")
        print "Yes, %s is equal to 5! Good job!" % attrib
        again = raw_input("Would you like to try again? (Y/N): ")
        print again
        if again == again.isalpha():
            if again == "y" or "Y":
                os.system("cls")
                print attrib
                print check_att(attrib)
            elif again == "n" or "N":
                os.system("exit")
        else:
            os.system("cls")
            not_alpha1 = raw_input("Sorry, that's not a valid answer. Would you like to try again? (Y/N): ")
            print not_alpha1
            if not_alpha1 == "y" or "Y":
                os.system("cls")
                print attrib
                print check_att(attrib)
            elif not_alpha1 == "n" or "N":
                os.system("cls")
    else:
        sorry = raw_input("Sorry, %s is not equal to 5. Try again? (Y/N): " % attrib)
        print sorry
        if sorry == sorry.isalpha():
            if sorry == "y" or "Y":
                os.system("cls")
                print attrib
                print check_att(attrib)
            elif sorry == "n" or "N":
                os.system("exit")
        else:
            os.system("cls")
            not_alpha = raw_input("Sorry, that's not a valid answer. Would you like to try again? (Y/N): ")
            print not_alpha
            if not_alpha == "y" or "Y":
                os.system("cls")
                print attrib
                print check_att(attrib)
            elif not_alpha == "n" or "N":
                os.system("cls")

print askme
print check_att(askme)
```

The problem I'm having is the part where the program asks the user if they want to run the program again. This is what happens when I run the code:

```
Enter a number that is equal to 5: 5
5
Yes, 5 is equal to 5! Good job!
Would you like to try again? (Y/N): Y
Y
Sorry, that's not a valid answer. Would you like to try again? (Y/N):
```

I don't know how to get the program to recognize `Y` as a valid input. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just do `if not_alpha1 in ["y","Y"]:`

Comment: @idjaw That post helped me a little with clearing up confusion pertaining to the if statement itself, but not the overall problem I'm having.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if again == "y" or "Y":`, you need:

```
if again == "y" or again == "Y":
```

or:

```
if again.lower() == 'y':
```

However, you might be better off with a raw_input setup like this:

```
while True:
    entry = raw_input("Enter a number that is equal to 5: ")
    if entry == 5:
        break
    else:
        print("That's not right, please try again.")
```

The only way out of the `while` loop is to make it to `break`; this way you don't have to worry about what they type in.  If it's not 5, they don't go anywhere.

Comment: Is it really necessary to post this as answer? Im pretty sure that this question is a duplicate

Comment: It took all of twenty seconds to write the answer, the OP had an error in the code, and hopefully this is helpful. And @Jim-Lewis pointed out a second error I missed too.

Answer (score 0):

```
if again == again.isalpha():
```

I don't think this is what you want.  `again.isalpha()` returns True or False, so it doesn't make sense to compare that to the value of `again`.
You probably intended:

```
if again.isalpha():
```

Also,

```
if again == "y" or "Y":
```

This probably doesn't do what you think it does.  It does a logical 'or'
of "y" and "Y",  then compares that result to `again`.   It is not a synonym
for

```
if again == "y" or again == "Y":
```

which is probably what you intended.

Comment: This helped with recognizing the input for the question asking the user if they want to run the program again. The problem I'm having now is being able to print `askme` again and change the user's input, then run through the `check_att` function again.